# Cannot find the Contact Dashboard

Tags: contacts, dashboard

I am running 4.7.8 on Wordpress and cannot find the Contact Dashboard.  I see Dashboard for Contributions, Events and Mailings but not under Contacts.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: may be you are looking for http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fuser&reset=1&id=1 - you can find the dashboard against action button

Answer (score 2):

Steve - there is not a Dashboard per se just for Contacts as there is for Contributions etc. If there was, what would it be showing in your opinion in case that clarifies your question enough to point you to what does exist.

Comment: So is the only way to get to a list of the contacts is via the search?  The documentation speaks to editing contacts, etc. but does not really state how to get to that point.  I thought that there would be a Contact Dashboard link that would bring up a list of all of the contacts similar to Memberships for example.

Comment: Hi Steve. I think that everyone would have a different view of what such a dashboard might encompass, and between Smart Groups, Search, Advanced Search and Contact Reports there are many many ways to pull together lists of contacts. Perhaps if you could spell out further what you hope to have as your standard 'overview' of contacts then someone can probably offer a recipe to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that gives you an instant 'let's see our Contacts is to just click in the QuickSearch (top left - white box) and hit Enter.

In that single click you get the 'Advanced Search' outcome of 'see all contacts' in A-Z order. If you create a Profile that has fields in that you would prefer instead of what is shown as default, you can then set this as your your default view in Admin > Customise > Search Preferences ie at civicrm/admin/setting/search?reset=1